# Byte-Stream Attack on a SerializationProxy: is it safer?

Tags: java, security, serialization

**Post Structure**:

1. Scenario
2. Question
3. Code and Output
4. Additional Info/Comments

**1. 
Scenario**
Given that I can edit the serialized byte-stream of the (private nested) SerializedProxy (of a Serializable class) to break the invariant of the SerializedProxy itself, I can, consequently, alter the instance being de-serialized.

In such a scenario where I have access to the serialized form of the SerializedProxy class, the byte-stream attack on the class being serialized is just as easy *without enforcing invariants* in the readResolve().

**2. Question**

Is the purported safety of the SerializationProxy approach -- wrt byte-stream attack -- purely based on the assumption that the contents of either the serialized form or the source code of the SerializedProxy would always be unavailable to the attacker? If not, have I misunderstood or missed some part of implementation here?

**3.Code**
        (Note: the Serializer is a util class that writes the serialized object to a file.)

3.1 ***Serialize the proxy with value 5***.

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.io.InvalidObjectException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    public class SerializationProxyTest implements Serializable
    {
        final int id;

        private SerializationProxyTest(int val)
        {
            id = val;
        }

        private void writeObject() throws InvalidObjectException, IOException
        {
            throw new InvalidObjectException("Invalid object called for Serialization: proxy not found.");
        }


        private Object writeReplace()
        {
            System.out.println("writeReplace 1 ");
            return new SerializationProxy(this);

        }

        private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable
        {
            final int id;

            SerializationProxy(SerializationProxyTest obj)
            {
                this.id = obj.id;
            }

            /* private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException
            {

                oos.defaultWriteObject();

            } */

            private Object readResolve()
            {
                System.out.println("readResolve step 1 ");
                return new SerializationProxyTest(this.id);
                // return "Something Else!";

            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
        {

            Serializer.serializeObject(new SerializationProxyTest(5));

            SerializationProxyTest spt = (SerializationProxyTest) Serializer.deserializeObject("/home/code/java/serialized_proxy_class.ser");

            System.out.println("stored variable is:  " + spt.id);
        }
    }
```

3.1 output:

> ```
>    [java]$ java SerializationProxyTest
>             writeReplace 1 
>             readResolve 1 
>             object is: SerializationProxyTest@4eec7777
>             stored variable is:  5
> ```
>
> aced 0005 7372 0029 5365 7269 616c 697a
>   6174 696f 6e50 726f 7879 5465 7374 2453
>   6572 6961 6c69 7a61 7469 6f6e 5072 6f78
>   793b 8ab7 89f9 dd6d aa02 0001 4900 0269
>   6478 7000 0000 **05**

3.2 ***Alter the serialized SerializedProxy to change the value of variable to 6***.

> aced 0005 7372 0029 5365 7269 616c 697a
>   6174 696f 6e50 726f 7879 5465 7374 2453
>   6572 6961 6c69 7a61 7469 6f6e 5072 6f78
>   793b 8ab7 89f9 dd6d aa02 0001 4900 0269
>   6478 7000 0000 **06**

3.3 ***Initialize the Serializable class by de-serializing*** the altered SerializedProxy: the SerializationProxyTest class is initialized with 6 instead of 5.

```
                SerializationProxyTest spt = (SerializationProxyTest) Serializer.deserializeObject("/home/code/java/serialized_proxy_class.ser");

            System.out.println("stored variable is:  " + spt.id);

        [java]$ java SerializationProxyTest
    writeReplace 1 
    readResolve 1 
    object is: SerializationProxyTest@4eec7777
    stored variable is:  6
```

**4.Additional Info/Comment**: the assumption of some inherent "safety" of the SerializedProxy approach is only a curiosity arising out of reading "Effective Java". Another assumption made here is that the attacker could -- by trial and error -- make an effective change to the byte-stream even without the knowledge of the class structure.

Answer (score 0):

When deserialising, the serial proxy must enforce the same invariants as the constructor (or that of a static creation method if you are going that route). This is usually achieve by the serial proxy using the public constructor (or method) to create the real object.

In the question's code the invariant that `id` is always 5 is in the static creation method (`main`). The serial proxy code does not use that.

Note: Your `SerializationProxyTest` is subclassable. Java byte code does not require a class to have a constructor, and therefore it is not necessary for the base class to have an accessible constructor. In general any non-final public or protected methods of your class may be overridable.

Also note, there are corrections in the serialisation chapter of 3rd edition Effective Java - don't use early versions.

Comment: Shouldn’t the Proxy maintain the invariant for/of the class it is proxy-ing? For instance, in my question above, I’d expect the SerializationProxy to establish the same invariant as that of the SerializationProxyTest instance which gets created with id = 5 inside the main method.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment: re-reading your answer clarifies things. Also, thanks for info about the previous version being outdated.